# How to make speed of scrolling more slower in this jQuery scrolling script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, jquery-plugins

Currently in example `speed` and `step` both are are `1`. but i need much slower speed of scrolling. How to get full control over speed.

I want the clouds to move much slower

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/cHZG6/1/

**Code**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scrollingBackground = function(options) {
        // settings and defaults.
        var settings = options || {};
        var speed = settings.speed || 1;
        var step = settings.step || 1;
        var direction = settings.direction || 'rtl';
        var animStep;

        // build up a string to pass to animate:
        if (direction === 'rtl') {
            animStep = "-=" + step + "px";
        }
        else if (direction === 'ltr') {
            animStep = '+=' + step + "px";
        }

        var element = this;

        // perform the animation forever:
        var animate = function() {
            element.animate({
                backgroundPosition: animStep + " 0px"
            }, speed, animate);            
        };
        animate();
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#header").scrollingBackground({
    speed: 1,
    step: 1,
    direction: 'ltr'
});

$("#header-2").scrollingBackground({
    speed: 1,
    step: 1,
    direction: 'rtl'
});
```

Comment: You want the clouds to move much slower?

Comment: @Reigel - yes right. when I use 0.5 or -1, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase the `speed` property that will slow down the scroll because it increases the delay between the step. I tried it with a value of 100 and it looked pretty smooth still.

Answer (score 2):

bigger ammount of `speed` makes the cloud move slow.

bigger ammount of `step` makes the cloud move fast.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/cHZG6/2/)

Comment: Do we need both? I want smooth but slow scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method you might want to consider is using the Spritely library. It has a [`pan()`](http://spritely.net/documentation/#Panning_a_background_image_with_the_pan%28%29_method) method that allows you to configure the speed, fps and direction and is very similar to what you are trying to do. You may prefer their implementation if you cannot get yours to work to your satisfaction.